# Why am i getting 503 error when 'npm access resctricted'

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a problem with setting my currently-publicly-published npm package. What I want is to set its public status to restricted or private.
it should be `npm access restricted <npm-package>`, but I'll get this:

**npm ERR! code E503
npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable - POST https://registry.npmjs.com/-/package//access - Service Unavailable**

[image]

Does anyone notice, what's wrong here?
Appreciate it!

Comment: Try again. Service Unavailable errors are often transient.

Comment: I tried multiple times, but it won't get pass the E503 ... i tried npm access public <...> and this got to run just fine, but not with restricted

Comment: Are you on a paid npm account? https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages

Comment: Thank you, I just saw that Notification of npm, that having a paid subscription is necessary in order to make it private.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my sharp sight and [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx)  for pointing out, that a paid subscription is needed in order to make packages private.